# HTML 5 feature detection - required attribute on input fields - does it degrade gracefully?

Tags: html, input, required, graceful-degradation

I want to use the `required` attribute on one of my input fields. I have already coded in the JS version of it, but for completeness' sake, why not include the HTML 5 as well (at the very least save trouble for non JS users).

Is it safe to just add `required` to the input, it does it not degrade gracefully? If it doesn't, then how can I check for its support (without Modernizr)?

Comment: Modernizr is the best and most popular script for checking browsers compability. If you don't want to use Modernizr, you have to write JavaScript script file which does that you want... It's too hard if you are not JS guru. My advice is using Modernizr or forget about checking HTML 5 support. :)

Comment: I don't see the point in having to load an entire JS library to check support for one attribute. I'm asking how to detect browser support for it, obviously using JS. To make it clear, I want to feature detect not browser detect.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `<!DOCTYPE html>` then there's no problem adding the `required` attribute.

You can feature detect using this JS:

```
'required' in document.createElement('input');
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Note that Safari does not actually support the `required` attribute but still response with `true` for the statement above.